# How to shuffle a list in Siri Shortcuts

Tags: sirishortcuts

I want to randomly permute a list using a default source of randomness. The only reference for "shuffle" that I've found is an option in the Play Music action.

In other words, how can I create an action that receives a list as an input and returns another list with the same elements, but in random order?

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to shuffle a list of text items, and found the stupidest possible answer:

Use the "Filter Files" action on your list, even though it's not a list of files. Clear out any filters that are there. Then set "Sort by" to "Random."